# Procurar em List(Of String) - Case insensitive

Tags: .net, vb.net

Como procurar uma `String` em uma `List(Of String)` sem considerar o caso?
Estou usando .net 2.0.

`Contains` não permite passar nenhum parâmetro adicional. Tentei usar `Find` mas também não funcionou.

```
Dim v_list As New List(Of String)(New String() {"a", "b", "c"})
Dim v_contains As Boolean
v_contains = v_list.Contains("A")
v_contains = v_list.Find(Function(x) String.Compare(x, "A", True))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não serve o Exists?

```
    Dim v_list As New List(Of String)(New String() {"a", "b", "c"})
    Dim v_contains As Boolean
    v_contains = v_list.Exists(Function(x) String.Compare(x, "A", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) = 0)
```

ou se for usar o Find

```
Dim find = v_list.Find(Function(x) String.Compare(x, "A", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) = 0)
```

Comment: Deveria funcionar, mas não estou conseguindo usar nenhuma dessas soluções, não sei se é por causa da versão do .NET ou algum erro meu. Por hora vou usar um For Each mesmo e quando estiver com mais tempo verifico melhor e escolho uma resposta.

Comment: estranho... tem certeza que sua versão do .net está como 2.0? acabei de testar aqui e foi

Comment: É mesmo estranho. Testando com uma aplicação console nova (2.0) funcionou. Porém na aplicação Web que estou trabalhando não compila e nem lista qual foi o erro.

Comment: Parece que para web não funciona a função inline no argumento do `Exists`. Usando `AddressOf` funcionou (exemplo na minha resposta).

Answer (score 3):

Os problemas que vejo nesse código:

- O método `Find` vai retornar um item da lista, portanto uma String. Mas você declarou `v_contains` como Boolean.
- O predicado do `Find` precisaria retornar um valor booleano, mas não é o que o `String.Compare` faz (ele retorna um número positivo, negativo, ou zero).

Uma solução possível:

```vb
Dim v_list As New List(Of String)(New String() {"a", "b", "c"})
Dim v_contains As String
v_contains = v_list.Find(Function(x) x.ToUpper() = "A") ' "a"
```

Comment: Não seria uma boa usar o `Count`?

Comment: @jbueno Sim, `Count<T>()` é outra possibilidade. Para ser sincero, não sei qual é a solução mais recomendada, não tenho tanta prática com .net.

Comment: `Count<T>()` não funciona, já que vem do Linq - que só foi introduzido no .NET 3.5, e o AP mencionou que está usando .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

A solução aceita não estava funcionando para minha aplicação Web, apesar de funcionar normalmente numa aplicação de console.
A solução encontrada foi usar `AddressOf` ao invés de colocar a função inline.

Abaixo como ficou o Default.aspx.vb:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim list As New List(Of String)
        Dim exists As Boolean

        list.Add("B")
        list.Add("A")

        exists = list.Exists(AddressOf check)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function check(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
        Return String.Compare(s, "a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) = 0
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Para passar uma string a ser buscada, seria necessário usar um membro `Private` da classe